# SQL Server 2012 Assistance with JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

The human resources manager needs a listing of employees by last name, their dependents first name, and dependent birth dates. The relevant output columns are emp_last_name from the employee table and dep_name and dep_date_of_birth from the dependent table. Use alias table names. Name each column appropriately. Sort the result table by emp_last_name. Use the CAST statement to produce a listing that fits easily on one page.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT emp_last_name"Employee Last Name", 
        dep_name"Dependent Name", 
       CAST(dep_date_of_birth as char(12))"Dependent Date of Birth"
from employee dependent
ORDER BY emp_last_name;
```

But I cannot figure out how to join it because there are so many dependents with the same last name. And NO this is NOT homework. I'm teaching myself SQL Server and I'm having a few issues. Just trying to get some assistance from those who know what they are doing.

Comment: how are the tables designed? What are their columns? Do you have multiple tables or just table referring only to itself?

Comment: why do you need to use join?

Comment: I don't have to use JOIN i just assumed that was the easiest way to do it. the tables are: Employee with columns emp_last_name, emp_first_name, emp_ssn, emp_superssn, emp_dateofbirth, emp_city, emp_state, emp_zip, emp_phone and Dependent (table) with columns: dep_emp_ssn, dep_name, dep_gender, dep_date_of_birth, dep_relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a JOIN

```
SELECT e.emp_last_name "Employee Last Name", 
        d.dep_name "Dependent Name", 
       CAST(d.dep_date_of_birth as char(12))"Dependent Date of Birth"
from employee e INNER JOIN dependent d ON e.emp_ssn = d.dep_emp_ssn
ORDER BY emp_last_name;
```

Or, you can join the tables like this:

```
SELECT e.emp_last_name "Employee Last Name", 
        d.dep_name "Dependent Name", 
       CAST(d.dep_date_of_birth as char(12))"Dependent Date of Birth"
from employee e, dependent d 
WHERE e.emp_ssn = d.dep_emp_ssn
ORDER BY emp_last_name;
```

If you also want to include employees without dependants, use LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT e.emp_last_name "Employee Last Name", 
        d.dep_name "Dependent Name", 
       CAST(d.dep_date_of_birth as char(12))"Dependent Date of Birth"
from employee e LEFT JOIN dependent d ON e.emp_ssn = d.dep_emp_ssn
ORDER BY emp_last_name;
```